# Define a different length enum based on #defined number

Tags: c++, enums

Assume that I have

```
#define l 4
```

I want an enum that looks like the following

```
enum Biscuits{
b1, b2, b3, b4
}
```

In other words, the length of Biscuits is dependent on what l is. The only way I can think of is to create another #defined variable that contains b1,b2,b3,b4 and then use that to define Biscuits. Is there any other way?

Comment: You will have to use preprocessor magic. It's horrible, but Boost.Preprocessor helps a bit. It can definitely be done.

Comment: Maybe you need to use preprocessor recursion.

Comment: Preprocessor recursion, that's the keyword I was looking for.

Comment: @Mr.Fegur deferred expressions will also help you

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple (unless you have to much variations):

```
#if l == 1
enum Biscuits{ b1 };
#elif l == 2
enum Biscuits{ b1, b2 };
#elif ...
#endif
```

Avoiding preprocessor magic improves readability.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how flexible you want your code to be. I suggest using:

```
enum Biscuits{

#ifndef l
#error l is not defined
#else
#if (l >= 2 )
   b1, b2
#endif

#if (l >= 4 )
   , b3, b4
#endif

#if (l >= 6 )
   , b5, b6
#endif

#if (l >= 8 )
   , b7, b8
#endif

#endif

};
```